# How to call my view controller method into appdelegate.m?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having action for login button in view controller but i have to use some condition in `appdelegate.m` that if user logged in already then `viewcontroller` login action method will fire and if not logged in then only login page will open?
Please help me

in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"IsFirstTime"])
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    HomePageVC *lvc = [storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomePageVC"];
    [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:lvc animated:NO];
}
else
{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"IsFirstTime"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}



return YES;
}
```

in viewcontroller.m

```
- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender

{
        [self.indicator startAnimating];//The ActivityIndicator Starts Animating Here

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:BaseUrl@"login"]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:60.0];

        [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


        [request addValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *mapData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName=gautam.kar@eyeforweb.com&userPassword=1234567&api_key=ZWZ3QDEyMw==&api_password=456789"];

        NSData *postData = [mapData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        [request setHTTPBody:postData];


        NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            if(error == nil)
            {
                NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                NSLog(@"jsondic= %@",jsonDic);

                NSDictionary *userDataDic = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"record"];

                [DataModel setEmailAdd:[userDataDic objectForKey:@"emailAdd"]];
                [DataModel setName:[userDataDic objectForKey:@"Name"]];
                [DataModel setCity:[userDataDic objectForKey:@"city"]];
                [DataModel setCountry:[userDataDic objectForKey:@"country"]];
                [DataModel setRegistrationID:[userDataDic objectForKey:@"registrationID"]];
                [DataModel setPhoneNo:[userDataDic objectForKey:@"phoneAdd"]];
                [DataModel setState:[userDataDic objectForKey:@"state"]];
                [DataModel settimeZone:[userDataDic objectForKey:@"timezone"]];
                [DataModel setDisclaimer:[userDataDic objectForKey:@"disclaimer"]];


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [self.indicator stopAnimating];//The ActivityIndicator Stops Animating when Response Arrives

                    NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"text= %@",text);

                    NSError *error = nil;
                    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

                    [self checkUserSuccessfulLogin:json];
                });
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [self.indicator stopAnimating];
                });
                NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.description);
            }
        }];

        [postDataTask resume];

}

- (void)checkUserSuccessfulLogin:(id)json
{
    //  NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)json;


    if ([[dictionary allKeys] containsObject:@"login"])
    {
        if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"login"] boolValue])
        {

            NSString *strID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"textField1Text"];
            NSString *strPWD = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"textField2Text"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[dictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"CurrentUserLoggedIn"];
            NSString *strUser = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"CurrentUserLoggedIn"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
            [self saveLoginFileToDocDir:dictionary];

            UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                                            HomePageVC *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomePageVC"];
                                           [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Unsuccessful, Try again.");
            UIAlertView *alertLogin = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Wrong Username Or Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertLogin show];
        }
    }
}

- (void)saveLoginFileToDocDir:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSArray *pListpaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *pListdocumentsDirectory = [pListpaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [pListdocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Login.plist"];

    BOOL flag = [dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:true];

    if (flag)
    {
        NSLog(@"Saved");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Saved");
    }

}

- (NSDictionary *)getLoginFileFromDocDir
{
    NSArray*pListpaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,  YES);
    NSString*pListdocumentsDirectory = [pListpaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [pListdocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Login.plist"];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    return dict;
}
```

Comment: you have already done this in your code you just need to check with nsuserdefault is that first time that value is nil so open login screen and on login sucess make that nsuserdeafult value change and then again that your coding going to be else and fire login api code

Comment: i when i am doing this above code then when i am editing the profile information and then saving it will not show the edited information, it will show when i have to do sin out and again login thwn edited information will show? therefore i want that login weservice will call at the time of opening the application

Comment: do yo have any webservices that called when you update profile information? if not then you are save the response of dictionary in nsuserdeafult then on update update dictionary value and store in your nsuserdeafult

Comment: yes i am having webservice for saving the edited data

Comment: then get the updateed data and overrire old dictionary that you have stored in nsuserdeafult

Comment: i am not getting please explain me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114709/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-abhi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is not to check your controller in AppDelegate.m, even though that is what you're asking.

Your real problem is " how can I access data from two different places ? ".

Right now, you're telling AppDelegate he "knows" your view controllers. It shouldn't.

What you need is one (actually a lot more but you'll learn that with time) new class, that handles the Login calls and state, and all that is login related.

Call that class the... `LoginManager`.

In that class, you could have some methods, like Login() or Logout(), or anything you would like.

Now you have an external source of data, your login manager knows everything he musts knows about the login. You should even add some properties, like a boolean `IsLoggedIn` or anything you might need.

And that source of data is what AppDelegate needs to know. Not the controllers. With that kind of architecture, EVERYONE that needs the login information can access it from that class (which could / should be a `singleton` class, look it up on the internet, its very easy.

In your viewcontroller, you can simply do `Loginmanager.login`, and in appdelegate, you can check `.isloggedin`.

That helps you a lot, because you don't have to instantiate view controllers in appdelegate, which is really a lot of work. You're splitting the work and the tasks between classes, which is what a good programmer does. Remember, your class should have only one job, not more, not less. Your VC handles the user inteface, not the webservic calls, not the login, nothing. If it does, it means you need to create another class :)

Once you've implemented all that (read my answer as many times as necessary to make sure you understand), you'll have no problem accessing that kind of data in other place of your app.

Note that you shouldn't abuse singleton classes or static classes (especially static), but again, you'll probably make many mistakes and learn from them, like we all did when we started.

Answer (score 0):

Create your ViewController Object like below,

```
viewcontroller *objYourVC=[[viewcontroller alloc]init];
```

Now call method from `Appdelegate` like below:

```
[objYourVC functionToBeCalled:nil];
```

OR

```
[objYourVC functionToBeCalled:self];
```

Example,

```
if(AlreadyLogin){

    //call viewcontroller method

    viewcontroller *objYourVC=[[viewcontroller alloc]init];

    [objYourVC functionToBeCalled:nil];

}
```